# How to make a tuple from a tuple?

Tags: c++, templates, tuples

For example, I have a convert template (any existing library to do it?)

```
template<class T> struct Convert;
template<> struct Convert<T0> {typedef C0 Type;};
template<> struct Convert<T1> {typedef C1 Type;};
template<> struct Convert<T2> {typedef C2 Type;};
```

From the convert, It convert

```
std::tuple<T0, T1, T2>; // version A
```

To

```
std::tuple<C0, C1, C2>; // version B
```

Any way to do it generally, like

```
template<class tupleA, template<class> class Convert>
{
    typedef .... tupleB;
}
```

Some other questions:
(1) Can I get its variadic parameters from a specific tuple?
(2) If so, can I use convert on the variadic parameters?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, could you please rephrase the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
template <typename... Args>
struct convert;

template <typename... Args>
struct convert<std::tuple<Args...>>
{
    typedef std::tuple<typename Convert<Args>::Type...> type;
};
```

Here is an example program:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template<class T> struct Convert;
template<> struct Convert<int>  {typedef bool Type;};
template<> struct Convert<char> {typedef int Type;};
template<> struct Convert<bool> {typedef char Type;};

template <typename... Args>
struct convert;

template <typename... Args>
struct convert<std::tuple<Args...>>
{
    typedef std::tuple<typename Convert<Args>::Type...> type;
};

int main()
{
     static_assert(
        std::is_same<
            convert<std::tuple<int, char, bool>>::type,
            std::tuple<bool, int, char>
        >::value, ""
    );
}
```

***[Demo](http://ideone.com/zqWCYy#view_edit_box)***

Comment: Thanks. If I cannot change the declaration of `convert'. How can I do it?

Comment: Now I got it. Thank you very much! Before I thought you change my `Convert`, but you didn't.

Comment: @user1899020 Ok great! Glad I could help

Comment: Can you compile? I cannot compile it on VC++ Nov 2012 CTP. it shows error C2027: use of undefined type 'convert<std::tuple<int,char,bool,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>>'
on the next line of `is_same` line.

Comment: @user1899020 Are you using the same code? Try including `<type_traits>`. If that doesn't work, it might be that Visual C++ doesn't support some C++11 features this code is using.

Comment: I already added `<type_traits>`. Maybe due to the compiler. It goes to the incomplete `convert<Arg...>` and doesn't go to `convert<tuple<Args..>>`. Any other ways? Thanks.

Comment: @user1899020 I wouldn't understand why it goes to the incomplete type... Are you sure you're using the *exact* same code in this example? The demo I provide compiles fine.

Comment: Yes. The compiler tries to match `template <typename... Args> struct convert;` which are not defined (or incomplete).

Comment: @user1899020 I just found out: This doesn't work because template specialization in Visual Studio 2010  doesn't work with typedef'd types. And I don't know a way around this, sorry.