# How to convert a tuple type to another tuple type with VC2012?

Tags: c++, templates, tuples

For example, I have a convert template

```
template<class T> struct Convert;
template<> struct Convert<T0> {typedef C0 Type;};
template<> struct Convert<T1> {typedef C1 Type;};
template<> struct Convert<T2> {typedef C2 Type;};
```

From the convert, It convert

```
std::tuple<T0, T1, T2>; // version A
```

To

```
std::tuple<C0, C1, C2>; // version B
```

Any way to do it generally, like

```
template<class tupleA, template<class> class Convert>
{
    typedef .... tupleB;
}
```

[Here is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618938/how-to-make-a-tuple-from-a-tuple/17619059?noredirect=1#17619059). But it doesn't compile on VC2012 and VC++ Nov 2012 CTP. Any way to let it work on VC++? Thanks a lot!

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13238487/1090079) (and perhaps [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35515)) for how to enable *variadic templates* in `VC++ Nov 2012 CTP`.

Comment: Wait, am I misunderstanding, or do you want the constructor of `std::tuple` that *For all i in sizeof...(UTypes), initializes ith element of the tuple with std::get<i>(other).*

Comment: @refp I am using VC++ Nov 2012 CTP. And I select it in VC++. But it still doesn't work with the old answer. In your suggested answer, it mentioned toolchain. What is this and how to install it? Thanks.

Comment: @chris No. I just create a new tuple type.